# How can i access the Recycle Bin in Azure?

Tags: azure

I had a virtual machine that i have deleted. The machine had Microsoft Defender Cloud running and reported some malaware:

```
    'DisguisedXMRigMiner' malware was detected on a Microsoft SQL server.
     Affected Virtual Machine:
     TestVM1
```

Firstly it says its says its detected on Microsoft SQL server and reports its a VM ?
I have deleted that VM about 2 days ago , searched all resources in Azure and it is not present,  but it still reports the error .

Is there a recycle bin I can access that I can permanently delete the resource ?
How can i resolve this ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can access the permanently deleted resource in Azure. There is a special feature that Azure provides called Soft Delete. When Soft Delete is enabled for a resource, it retains the resource and its metadata for a specified period of time(14 DAYS to 90 DAYS) after deletion. During this time, you can restore the deleted resource to its previous state.

To access the Soft Delete(Recycle bin) feature, you need to go to the resource's management menu in the Azure portal, click on the "Soft delete" option and use it. Once Soft Delete is enabled, any resources deleted after that will be moved to the "Soft delete" option under the "Operations" section of the resource management menu.

Comment: Is there something that has pictures that can show the steps ?

Comment: Can you list some resources supporting this feature? or provide a link to relevant documentation

Comment: Yes i need some documentation supporting this and how it can be enabled